Is the Inverse Fourier Transform of the Lindhard response function the Yukawa potential?
Is the Inverse Fourier Transform (IFT) of the (Inverse) Lindhard response function in the static limit the Yukawa potential?
The most basic and general form of the Lindhard function is:
\begin{equation}
\chi_{Lind}(q,\omega)=\frac{1}{L^{d}}\sum_{k}\frac{n_{k}-n_{k+q}}{\hbar(\omega+i\eta)+\varepsilon_{k}-\varepsilon_{k+q}}    
\end{equation}
Thus, I get for the Lindhard response in the static limit $\omega+i\eta\rightarrow 0$ also using the long-wavelength limit $q\rightarrow 0$ after some algebra:
\begin{equation}
\chi_{Lind}(q,0)=\frac{\kappa^{2}}{4\pi}\Leftrightarrow \chi^{-1}_{Lind}(q,0)=\frac{4\pi}{\kappa^{2}}\stackrel{q\rightarrow 0}{=}\frac{4\pi}{\kappa^{2}+q^{2}}
\end{equation}
We recognize the result as the Fourier Transform (FT) of the Yukawa potential. Applying consequently the Inverse Fourier Transform $\mathcal{F}^{-1}[\cdot]$ on both sides
\begin{equation}
\stackrel{\mathcal{F}^{-1}[\cdot]}{\Leftrightarrow} \mathcal{F}^{-1}[\chi^{-1}_{Lind}(q,0)]=\mathcal{F}^{-1}\bigg[\mathcal{F}[V_{Yukawa, \kappa}(r,r')]\bigg] \Leftrightarrow
\end{equation}
yields
The Inverse Fourier Transform (IFT) of the static limit of the inverse Lindhard response is the Yukawa potential:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{F}^{-1}[\chi^{-1}_{Lind}(q,0)]=V_{Yukawa, \kappa}(r,r')=\frac{\exp{\{-\kappa |r-r'|\}}}{|r-r'|}
\end{equation}
We used the well known fact, that for the Hartree kernel in momentum space
\begin{equation}
f_{H}(q)=\mathcal{F}[V_{Yukawa, \kappa=0}(r)]=\frac{4\pi}{q^{2}+\kappa^{2}}\bigg|_{\kappa=0}=\frac{4\pi}{q^{2}}    
\end{equation}
accounts. Since
\begin{equation}
f_{H}(q)=\frac{4\pi}{q^{2}}=\mathcal{F}[V_{Yukawa, \kappa\rightarrow 0}(r,r')]=\lim_{\kappa\rightarrow 0}\int\int drdr'\frac{\exp{\{-\kappa|r-r'|\}}}{|r-r'|}\exp{\{-iq\cdot(r-r')\}}    
\end{equation}
&
\begin{equation}
V_{Yukawa, \kappa\rightarrow 0}(r,r')=\lim_{\kappa\rightarrow 0}\frac{\exp{\{-\kappa|r-r'|\}}}{|r-r'|}=\frac{1}{|r-r'|}=f_{H}(r,r')    
\end{equation}
Thank you very much in advance

The question may be improved if you can summarize your derivations in succinct, natural language. Most answerers do not have the time to check the derivation line by line, but if you summarize your line of thought in natural language, they can see whether certain parts of it look suspicious, and only then do they need to go to the respective equations to verify their correctness.

@wzkchem5 I mean Ok, but ... Nobody is forced to look into the specifics, if she or he doesn't want to. The question is definitely succinct: Is the Inverse Fourier Transform of the (Inverse) Lindhard response function the Yukawa potential?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Nobody is "forced" to look at the specifics, but if you are asked to make your question more succinct and you refuse to do so, and nobody answers it for long enough, and the moderation team agrees, then your question will be closed because it is deemed to be wasting space on the site. Whether or not you think the question is "definitely" succint would be irrelevant, and is a very subjective matter anyway, so let's not go back-and-forth about that.

We gave you a platform to publish your question in a place with a wide audience, for free, but that right is not unconditional. If this community thinks your question is not succinct enough, the question can be closed regardless of your opinion on the matter, and you can always publish your question somewhere else. Anyway, +1 and welcome to our community! I do agree with wzkchem5 since your question post's overall content is far longer than almost all questions on this site. In fact, I've seen all 4000+ questions and don't think I've seen one that asks to check such a long derivation.

@NikeDattani-NoFreeTime Ok. I condensed my question into the 7 most important equations

@LeonRedeker thanks, that is very appreciated! It looks much more manageable and also loads faster for me!
